# Windows live messenger installation on Server 2003 64bit

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-live

How to install windows live messenger on windows server 2003 64 bit enterprise edition?

Comment: What about downloading and installing it (http://download.live.com/?sku=messenger)? Any particular problem you encounter?

Comment: I deleted the OP's comment for unnecessary comments. Please remain civil.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.techspot.com/blog/129/how-to-run-windows-live-messenger-on-windows-xp-x64/) TechSpot article explains how it can be done. 8.1 is the only version officially still supported to work on Windows XP and Server 2003 64Bit if installed this way.

You effectively need to download the messenger.msi installer by itself. The Live Installer doesn't natively support Windows XP and Server 2003 64Bit and I doubt support will be built in with the launch of Windows 7 and Server R2.

[This](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/10/21/retrieve-windows-live-messenger-2009-standalone-individual-setup-installer-msi-from-web-download/) Digital Life article explains how to get the standalone installer of the latest version of a machine that already has Live Messenger installed.

Comment: It installs 8.1 messenger ,  i want to install the latest version

Comment: 8.1 is the only supported version that works on 64Bit Server 2008. 8.5 iteself does not. However I have updated the answer with information on how to get the latest installer of another machine.